# Select и js... обработка выборки на нескольких select

Tags: javascript, php

Мое почтение программистам и любителям программирования!
такой вопрос меня мучает несколько суток, решил обратиться к Вам:
есть несколько селектов. ПРи выборе любого из нескольких селектов должно происходить следующее: взять значения всех селектов, обратиться к БД с поиском данных, вывод на отдельную область... при выборе любого селекта происходит определенный вывод информации из БД... Все мне понятно, кроме одного: как сделать так, чтобы взять значения (value) всех селектов, и передать значения php для срабатывания поиска данных в БД?
Буду очень благодарен...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понятен вопрос. Что-то типа этого надо?

```
// берём ключ по которому искать
$query = "SELECT ... ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$n = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
$find1 = $n['fieldname1'];

// второй запрос ищем по ключу
$query = "SELECT ... WHERE f=".$find1;
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {    
    // всякие команды обработки результатов запроса
}
```

Если такой вопрос, код наверно можно в один запрос уложить (с mysql-подзапросом).

Comment: Кстати, у Вас в вопросе стоит метка "javascript".

Comment: по ходу, я неправильно изъяснился! SORRY!
все, что вы написали, будет происходить после обновления страницы или передачи данных для обработки на другую страницу! Мне нужно это сделать в реальном времени, то есть средствами JS... то, что Вы написали, умею делать! дело в том, что надо все обработать сначала средствами js, передать php для запросов в БД и потом только выводить в динамическую область страницы...

Comment: Наверно надо копать в сторону Ajax http://javascript.ru/ui/ajax